# What will be the connection URL, Driver class name and maven dependency for Pervasive db?

Tags: java, database, pervasive-sql

We are upgrading our project from jdk 7 to jdk 17. We are using Pervasive DB as our database.  What will be the connection URL, Driver class name and maven dependency for Pervasive db ?

Could you please tell me what will be Database connection string, Pom Dependency for pervasive db

I am not getting any kind of solution.

Comment: What version of Pervasive are you using?  Why do you think you need to change the connection string?  If you're using the Pervasive JDBC driver, the connection string doesn't change between JDKs.

Comment: Have you search for this information in the documentation?